# Chain multiple functions in Scala while a condition holds

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose we have 3 methods which all return an `Option`

```scala
import scala.util.Try

def divideSafe(d: Int): Option[Int] = Try(42 / d).toOption
def sqrtSafe(x: Double): Option[Double] = if(!math.sqrt(x).isNaN) Some(math.sqrt(x)) else None
def convertSafe(s: String): Option[Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption
```

Now I want to chain them while a condition holds. In my case, if the result from the previous method is defined then should go to the next one. And as long as the condition is false, then stop the operation and return a default value.

I can obtain the desired result with nested if-else statements:

```scala
def superSafe(d: Int, x: Double, s: String): Unit = {
  if (divideSafe(d).isDefined) {
    println(divideSafe(d).get.toString)
    if (sqrtSafe(x).isDefined) {
      println(sqrtSafe(x).toString)
      if (convertSafe(s).isDefined) {
        println(convertSafe(s).get.toString)
      } else {
        println("Converting failed")
      }
    } else {
      println("Sqrt failed")
    }
  } else {
    println("Dividing failed")
  }
}
```

Therefore:

`superSafe(1, -1, "5")` would print 42 and Sqrt failed
`superSafe(0, 4, "cat")` would print Dividing failed
`superSafe(42, 4, 1)` would print 1,2,1

However I want to avoid the nested if-else statements and I am interested if there is a functional way in Scala to solve this kind of problems.

I want something like `orElse` statement, but the other way around.

The desired function could be used like this:

```scala
divideSafe(42) ifThen("Dividing failed") sqrtSafe(-4) ifThen("Sqrt failed") convertSafe("cat") ifThen("Converting failed")
```

Comment: 1) https://dzone.com/articles/scala-comprehensions-options
2) https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-multiple-options-for-loop-comprehension
3) "For comprehensions" https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Validated.html http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html

Comment: Thank you for the resources! The Validated and Validation applicative functors seem to collect all the failures, however I might have really expensive operations, thus I am interested only in the first occurring failure and I don't want to evaluate the next ones.

Comment: And in the for comprehension I am not sure how to track the first operation where I obtained None

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `Option` which is not best suited for your use case. I believe `Either` would work better in your example because it can hold information about failure(`Left`) or about success (`Right`). If you rewrote your functions to use `Either` it might look like:

```
def divideSafe(d: Int): Either[String, Int] = Try(42 / d).toOption.toRight("Divide failed")
def sqrtSafe(x: Double): Either[String, Double] = math.sqrt(x) match {
   case s if s.isNaN => Left("Sqrt failed") //you can use pattern matching to calculate square just once
   case s => Right(s)
} 
def convertSafe(s: String): Either[String, Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption.toRight("Converting failed")
```

And then you could use `for comprehension` in your `superSafe` method:

```
def superSafe(d: Int, x: Double, s: String): Unit = {
  val r: Either[String, (Int, Double, Int)] = for { //for-comprehension shortcircuits
    r1 <- divideSafe(d) //if divideSafe fails it whole comprehension will return Left(Divide failed)
    r2 <- sqrtSafe(x) //if it succeds it will go further
    r3 <- convertSafe(s)
  } yield (r1,r2,r3)

  r match { 
    case Right((r1,r2,r3)) => { //you could move it inside yield, I splitted it for clarity
      println(r1)
      println(r2)
      println(r3)
    }
    case Left(e) => println(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe using a Try is better than a Either in this specific case, as the right-side information is always related to an exception.

Comment: @sachav That's a good point, but if OP insists on using strings for errors, he can use `Either`.

Comment: In the for comprehension gives me an error: cannot resolve symbol flatMap

Comment: It seems this error is due to I am using scala 2.11.8, but in 2.12.x should work

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik it totally makes sense to use other collection instead of Option here, and yes Try is enough. I rewrote it using Try and is working perfectly. Thank you for the ideas!

Comment: Yes, `Either` started being right-biased monad from [2.12](https://alvinalexander.com/photos/scala-either-left-right-2.12-biased-map-flatmap).

Comment: @sanyi14ka Great to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you like it more functional, you can try this:

```
import scala.util.Try

def divideSafe(d: Int): Option[Int] = Try(42 / d).toOption
def sqrtSafe(x: Double): Option[Double] = if(!math.sqrt(x).isNaN) Some(math.sqrt(x)) else None
def convertSafe(s: String): Option[Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption

def superSafe(d: Int, x: Double, s: String): Any = {
  divideSafe(d)
    .map(rd => sqrtSafe(x)
    .map(rx => convertSafe(s)
    .map(rs => (rd, rx, rs))
    .getOrElse((rd, rx, "Converting failed")))
    .getOrElse((rd, "Sqrt failed")))
    .getOrElse("Dividing failed")
}

println(superSafe(1, 1, "1"))
```